# Undefined namespace prefix when using yahoo weather query api

Tags: php, api, yahoo, weather

Keep getting namespace error when using the code below

```
<?php

    // error_reporting(0);

    $BASE_URL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";

    $yql_query = 'select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="austin, tx")';
    $result = file_get_contents($BASE_URL . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query) . "&format=xml");

    if ($result == true) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('yweather', 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0');
        $location = $xml->results->channel;

        if(!empty($location)){
            foreach($xml->results->channel->item as $item){
                $current = $item->xpath('yweather:condition');
                $temp = $current['temp'];

                echo $temp;
            }
        }
        else{
            echo '<h1>No weather for today</h1>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<p>Weather service is down</p>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Would be nice to know how the xml looks like.

Comment: Side note: change `&format=xml` to `&format=json` and then just `json_decode` the results and work with a simple PHP array!

Comment: That's because you're probably in the wrong namespace. Define the namespace you're using at the very top of the file, or include the files this script needs to run(namesapces included).

Comment: cant paste the xml.. use the url to see the xml http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+%2A+from+weather.forecast+where+woeid+in+%28select+woeid+from+geo.places%281%29+where+text%3D%22austin%2C+tx%22%29&format=xml

Comment: @jszobody would you mind showing and example?

Comment: If you print `print_r($item)` in the result didnt find the `yweather:condition`.please check once. So it throws warning

Comment: @titant3ch sure one sec

Comment: when printing $item i see SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [title] => Conditions for Austin, TX at 7:50 am CDT
    [link] => http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Austin__TX/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USTX0057_f.html
    [pubDate] => Thu, 12 Mar 2015 7:50 am CDT
    [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [guid] => USTX0057_2015_03_16_7_00_CDT
)

Comment: yes.exactly.you are trying to access non object `yweather:condition`.Its not there in `$item` result. what's your expected result?

Comment: something like <yweather:condition xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" code="26" date="Thu, 12 Mar 2015 6:50 am CDT" temp="53" text="Cloudy"/> then obtain the temp and text info

Comment: I don't know if you are aware that the domain xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0 is no longer valid. Yahoo changed it this year. query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/ is the current domain for weather requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, here's a solution using JSON instead of XML:

```
$BASE_URL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";

$yql_query = 'select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="austin, tx")';
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($BASE_URL . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query) . "&format=json"), true);

if(is_array($result)) {
    $location = $result['query']['results']['channel'];

    if(!empty($location)) {
        $temp = $result['query']['results']['channel']['item']['condition']['temp'];
        echo $temp;
    } else {
        echo '<h1>No weather for today</h1>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>Weather service is down</p>';
}
```

Tested locally on my machine.